# how to print entire block if it contains particular line with awk command?

Tags: awk, text-processing

I am trying to process network information from `lshw -c network` with awk command

the output looks like this:-

```
*-network:3
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0.3
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.3
   logical name: eth1
   version: 01
   serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
   size: 1GB/s
   capacity: 1GB/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: eth0
   serial: yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=vif link=yes multicast=yes
```

I want to print this in a tabular format but only if the block contains `bus info:`, here only 1st is the qualified block and will be printed format

final output:-

```
description   product   vendor   physical id   bus info ...
Ethernet..    I350 G..  Intel..  0.3           pci@0000:03:00.3
```

my best effort is:-

```
    lshw -c network | 
    awk -v FS=: 
    $0 ~ /*-network.*/ {
        v1 = NR; 
        v2 = ""; 
        v3 = 0
    } 

    NR > v1 && v3 == 0 {
        v2 = v2"@"$3
        } 

    $1 ~ /bus info.*/ {
        v3 = 1
        }  

    v3 == 1 {
        split(v2, ar, "@"); 
        for (t in ar) { print t}; 
        print $1
    }
```

with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have input date with tag(name) = value mappings it's best to first create an array to contain those mappings (`tag2val[]` below) and then you can analyze any combinations of fields being present and/or having specific values you like and print whatever fields you like in whatever order you like. For example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
/^[*]/ { prt() }
{
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    gsub(OFS," ")
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
    tag2val[tag] = val
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   flds, numFlds, fldNr) {
    numFlds = split("description,product,vendor,physical id,bus info",flds,/,/)
    if ( "bus info" in tag2val ) {
        if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
            for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
                tag = flds[fldNr]
                printf "%s%s", tag, (fldNr<numFlds ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
        for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++) {
            tag = flds[fldNr]
            val = tag2val[tag]
            printf "%s%s", val, (fldNr<numFlds ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
    delete tag2val
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
description         product                          vendor             physical id  bus info
Ethernet interface  I350 Gigabit Network Connection  Intel Corporation  0.3          pci@0000:03:00.3
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested:

This command works:-

```
lshw -c network | 
awk -v out='description\tproduct\tvendor\tphysical id\tbus info\tlogical name\tversion\tserial\twidth\tclock\tcapabilities\tconfiguration\tresources' 
    -v v1=0 -F ': ' 
' $0 ~ /*-network.*/ {
    if (v1 == 1) {print out;} 
    out = ""; 
    v1=0 
} 
$1 ~ /bus info.*/ { 
    v1 = 1
    } 
{ 
    out = out"\t"$2 
} 
END{ 
    if (v1 == 1) print out 
}'
```

Comment: That won't print the last record in the input if it contains `bus info` and it'll only print part of the data if/when it contains `: ` (imagine a product name like `Ethernet: version 2`) and it'll print all blocks up to and including the one containing `bus info`, not just the one containing it.

Comment: I think now it will print.

Comment: re-read the last part of my comment and think about where you're setting `v1=0`.

Comment: I updated and checked, this command, if there is any issue plz, give an example

Comment: The only remaining issue is it'll only print part of the data if/when it contains : (imagine a product name like `Ethernet: version 2`). See how [I used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60661230/1745001)  `tag = val = $0;
    sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",tag);
    sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)` instead of using fields to make it robust by splitting the line at the first `:` rather than at every `:`.